# Jade-php - Declare a Jade variable in a jade format only

Tags: pug

Assume we have

```
//- foo.jade
-   var foo= "bar"
```

when compiling (i'm using [gulp jade php)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jade-php)  the results will be:

```
<?php var foo="bar" ?>
```

Is possible to declare a variable in a jade format only?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, I'm using [jade-php](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jade-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, several days later i've figured something using the [filters](http://jade-lang.com/reference/filters/) functions
`:jade`

```
:jade
    - var foo="bar"
    p=foo
```

output:

```
<p>bar</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that's a possible thing with jade-php or gulp-jade-php. Why do you need to do it?

If you have the following the gulpfile and jade file:

*gulpfile.js*

```
var jade = require('gulp-jade-php');

gulp.task('templates', function() {
    gulp.src('./views/**/*.jade')
        .pipe(jade({
            locals: {
                data: {
                    subtitle: 'Subtitle'
                }
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

*foo.jade*

```
- var subtitle = data.subtitle
p!= subtitle
```

You could easily do the following:

*gulpfile.js*

```
var jade = require('gulp-jade-php');
var subtitle = 'Subtitle';
gulp.task('templates', function() {
    gulp.src('./views/**/*.jade')
        .pipe(jade({
            locals: {
                data: {
                    subtitle: subtitle
                },
                subtitle: subtitle
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

*foo.jade*

```
p!= subtitle
```

So I would transform the locals instead of solving this in jade.